# Cognito: User Pool Client OAuth Scope Limitation

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have multiple Resource Server w/ multiple scopes each (see structure below). There is a hard limit of 50 scopes per app client. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolclient). I want to have a configurable client that can have more than 50 scopes. Is there any way I can achieve that with Cognito User Pool?

Thank you in advance.

```
Resource Servers:
 Service1
  -read
  -write
 Service2
  -read
  -write
 ...
 Service50
  -read
  -write


App Client:
 Client1:
  -service1/read
  -service2/read
  ...
  -service50/read
 Client2: #Error (cannot have more than 50 scopes)
  -service1/read
  -service1/write
  -service2/read
  -service2/write
  ...
  -service50/read
  -service50/write
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feels like you may be over using Scopes in your authorization - it is worth being aware that there are alternative designs that scale better. My write up may help you - the blog also has code samples to demonstrate them: https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/

Comment: I updated my scope to represent high-level areas of the business that the token can access. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Gary Archer, another excellent OAuth article!  Thanks for putting the time and effort into your website.